# ←[106m whenever I type anything in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell

I started using powershell really recently and after changing my colors, it started to do this weird thing where it just shows my font size (afaik) after the thing I wrote. Also the number changes whenever I change the font size.

[image: the thing it does]

Comment: Looks like a mismatch in the set of ANSI escape sequences generated by the shell and the set supported by the console window.

Comment: how do I fix this mismatch?

Comment: Make sure "Legacy Console Mode" isn't turned on it your console window properties.  A mention of some of the new stuff that Powershell might be using... https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/new-experimental-console-features/

Comment: oh my god, everything looks so nice now! Thank you!

Comment: There's also Conhost vs Windows Terminal vs conemu

Comment: yeah, I know about the other terminals, I'm using powershell becuase I'm too lazy

Comment: Powershell is a shell, you can use it in any of the terminals.

Comment: oh well, guess you're right, maybe I'm gonna become a terminal user soon! :D